GET raw data from google drive using
I'm trying to make a "GET" data(folder Name, ID , type etc) from my google drive using googleapis
I'm using this code
const fetchGoogleDriveFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'&fields=files(id,name,mimeType,parents)`,
        {
          method: "GET", 
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
          },
        }
      ); 
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Google Drive Files:", data.files);
      } else {
        console.error("Error fetching Google Drive files:", response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Google Drive files:", error);
    }
  };

I'm currently trying two formats on the fetch() function
 `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'&fields=files(id,name,mimeType,parents)`

which doesnt show any error but the log shows as "[]" only
and
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

which works but it only logs the previously uploaded files. So far I've checked my scopes and access token, and all seems fine on my POV.
This is my Api routes
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google" 

export const authOptions = ({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "" ,
            clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
            authorization: { 
              params: 
              { 
                scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" 
                //
              } 
            },
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({token, user , account} : any){  
        if (account) {
          token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        }
        return token
      },
      async session({ session, token } : any) {
        const newSession = {
          ...session,
          accessToken: token.accessToken,
        }; 
        return newSession;
      },
    }
})
 
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}

looking at the Google API docs, my understanding is my scope should be authorized
can anyone help me out on this and hopefully help me understand this
